# How should the AnyStr be used?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I am pretty new to annotations in Python and trying to apply them to a project I am working. I can't really figure out the `AnyStr` type from the `typing` package.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr) say:

> AnyStr is a constrained type variable defined as AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', str, bytes)
>
> It is meant to be used for functions that may accept any kind of string without allowing different kinds of strings to mix.

So I get this like it is str or bytes.

In my project I have a function like this:

```
def x() -> Tuple[Optional[AnyStr], Optional[dict]]:
   if something:
      return logic1(), logic2()
   return None, None
```

`logic1` in this case returns an `AnyStr` and `logic2` a dict. However, `mypy` shows this error:

> Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[str, Dict[Any, Any]]", expected "Tuple[bytes, Dict[Any, Any]]")

I don't understand why this is seen as an error. As I understand `AnyStr`, the expected values should either be `Tuple[bytes, Dict[Any, Any]]` or `Tuple[str, Dict[Any, Any]]`.

Why is this an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr) give is for a function that accepts either flavour of string, and returns the same type:

> `def concat(a: AnyStr, b: AnyStr) -> AnyStr:`

With that in mind, here is how `AnyStr` could be used in your code:

```
def logic1(s:AnyStr) -> AnyStr:
    return 2 * s # For example

def logic2() -> dict:
    return {}

something = True

def x(s:AnyStr) -> Tuple[Optional[AnyStr], Optional[dict]]:
   if something:
      return logic1(s), logic2()
   return None, None
```

This passes through `mypy` with no problem.

If you simply want a type that might be either a string or a `bytes`, you would be better off with `Union[str,bytes]`:

```
def logic1() -> Union[str,bytes]:
    return 'hi'

def logic2() -> dict:
    return {}

something = True

def x() -> Tuple[Optional[Union[str,bytes]], Optional[dict]]:
   if something:
      return logic1(), logic2()
   return None, None
```

Comment: So does that mean that I need to have an AnyStr input parameter in my function to be able to pass a AnyStr as a return value, sounds weird in my ears... And I thought Optional[AnyStr] was the same as Optional[Union[str,bytes]] as these are the string types of AnyStr.

Comment: The description of `AnyStr` specifically describes this purpose: "It is meant to be used for functions that may **accept** any kind of string without allowing different kinds of strings to mix." That is a difference between `AnyStr` and `Union[str,bytes]`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing out the accept part. So AnyStr wont work if you have a function with no input params and logic like `x=bytevalue if random.randrange(2) == 0 else x=strvalue return x`